# how to get a cross table from nested dictionaries in a json file

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I would like to get a cross-table by using pandas dataframe with Python like this:

|  | Home | Away | Tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| played | 19 | 19 | 38 |
| wins | 10 | 8 | 18 |
| draws | 7 | 5 | 12 |
| loss | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| goals_for | 40 | 26 | 66 |
| goals_against | 17 | 19 | 36 |
| avg_goal_for | 2.1 | 1.4 | 1.7 |
| avg_goal_against | 0.9 | 1.0 | 0.9 |

and the json file is :

```
{
"get": "teams/statistics",
"response": {
    "fixtures": {
        "played": {
            "home": 19,
            "away": 19,
            "total": 38
        },
        "wins": {
            "home": 10,
            "away": 8,
            "total": 18
        },
        "draws": {
            "home": 7,
            "away": 5,
            "total": 12
        },
        "loses": {
            "home": 2,
            "away": 6,
            "total": 8
        }
    },
    "goals": {
        "for": {
            "total": {
                "home": 40,
                "away": 26,
                "total": 66
            },
            "average": {
                "home": "2.1",
                "away": "1.4",
                "total": "1.7"
            }
        },
        "against": {
            "total": {
                "home": 17,
                "away": 19,
                "total": 36
            },
            "average": {
                "home": "0.9",
                "away": "1.0",
                "total": "0.9"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

I don't know how to handle all nested dictionaries in an easy way.
Please someone can help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to process both halves of your `response` separately, using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to read the data, then splitting the column names to a multi-level index and then using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to move to a long format from the wide format. You can then drop the top-level index and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two dataframes:

```py
data = json.loads(jstr)

fixtures = pd.json_normalize(data['response']['fixtures'])
fixtures.columns = fixtures.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
fixtures = fixtures.stack(level=0)
fixtures.index = fixtures.index.droplevel()
fixtures
#         away  home  total
# draws      5     7     12
# loses      6     2      8
# played    19    19     38
# wins       8    10     18

goals = pd.json_normalize(data['response']['goals'])
goals.columns = goals.columns.str.split(r'\.(?!.*\.)', expand=True)
goals = goals.stack(level=0)
goals.index = goals.index.droplevel()
goals
#                 away home total
# against.average  1.0  0.9   0.9
# against.total     19   17    36
# for.average      1.4  2.1   1.7
# for.total         26   40    66

out = pd.concat([fixtures, goals])
```

Output:

```
                away home total
draws              5    7    12
loses              6    2     8
played            19   19    38
wins               8   10    18
against.average  1.0  0.9   0.9
against.total     19   17    36
for.average      1.4  2.1   1.7
for.total         26   40    66
```

Note, if desired you can rename the index column to match your question using

```py
out.index = ['draws', 'loses', 'played', 'wins', 'goals_against_average', 'goals_against_total', 'goals_for_average', 'goals_for_total']
```

Output:

```
                      away home total
draws                    5    7    12
loses                    6    2     8
played                  19   19    38
wins                     8   10    18
goals_against_average  1.0  0.9   0.9
goals_against_total     19   17    36
goals_for_average      1.4  2.1   1.7
goals_for_total         26   40    66
```

Note this code can be made more generic, by creating a dict of the sub-dictionary names and the appropriate splitting string, and then iterating that dict:

```py
parts = { 'fixtures' : '.', 'goals' : r'\.(?!.*\.)' }
dfs = []
for part in parts:
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['response'][part])
    df.columns = df.columns.str.split(parts[part], expand=True)
    df = df.stack(level=0)
    df.index = df.index.droplevel()
    dfs.append(df)

out = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Your solution is very straightforward and I am going to select it as a good solution. One more question: Just think that I had to simplify the JSON file by removing other  stuff, for example, other dictionaries at the same level of fixtures...Can your solution manage a more general case of nested dictionaries or other levels that I need to drop ?

Comment: @Alex See my edit; I've added some code which is a bit more generic but tbh if Lucas' code works that will probably be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to un-nest your dictionary, I recommend a recursive function to do so.

if you want to do something that works for any occasion you can do something such as

```py
final_dict = {}

def verify_keys(dicto):
    # this verify is dicto is a consistent block
    for val in dicto.values():
        keys = list(val.keys())
        equal = keys==['home', 'away', 'total']
        if not equal:
            return False
    return True

def append_to_unested_dict(dicto, my_dict, key):
    # this function adds data to your dictionary
    if verify_keys(dicto):
        for name, item in dicto.items():
            my_dict[f"{key}_{name}"] = item 
        return True
    return False

def deep_nested(dicto, my_dict, base_key=None):
    # this is the recursive fucntion
    for key, item in dicto.items():
        name_key = key if not base_key else f"{base_key}_{key}"
        appended = append_to_unested_dict(item, my_dict, name_key)
        if not appended:
            deep_nested(item, my_dict, key)
        

for key, item in response.items():
    if not isinstance(item, dict):
        continue
    deep_nested(item, final_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(final_dict).T
```

output

```
                       home     away    total
fixtures_played         19       19     38
fixtures_wins           10        8     18
fixtures_draws           7        5     12
fixtures_loses           2        6     8
goals_for_total         40       26     66
goals_for_average       2.1     1.4     1.7
goals_against_total     17       19     36
goals_against_average   0.9     1.0     0.9
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks a million for your time. To be honest, I haven't gone through your solution and it looks more "structured" compared to Nick's solution. In any case, I promise you that I will try it because it is very interesting if it can handle any kind of structured json file.